# A sphere (the world) in OpenGL ES on Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, 3d

Is there a way, using only Objective-C, that I can make a 3d sphere and then put texture on it to make it look like the earth. I am completely new to OpenGL ES for iOS so please keep it simple.

Comment: "Please keep it simple" and "just starting OpenGL-ES" are mutually exclusive...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Open-ended questions don't travel far here — it's better to bring a question that reflects research you've done so far and a specific place where you got stuck. What have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly, but you can find lots of samples that would require just copy paste to do that.

Take this for textured object:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/4404/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial-part-2-textures
And this to generate a sphere: http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/4631-How-to-make-textures-mapping-to-sphere

And if you combine those :-) you'll get a textured cube